# Starting a long task after page load

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, servlet-3.0

I'm currently working on a jsf based webapp. I'm using jsf 2.0, servlet 3 and primefaces.

The idea is:

After a User logs in he gets an info panel. This panel shows a loading sign. In the backend a rather long DB query is executed that generates a sum of his transactions. When the task is finished the panel should be updated to show the result.

First I tried to make a ajax call after the page has loaded (with hidden buttons fired by javascript and f:event) but the page only loaded half and the task never finished (I only made a dummy loop which counts to 10).

I also tried to make a workaround with hidden progressbars but I encountered the same problem: The completed Listener wouldn't execute right after page load.

What I have or inted to use: The panel itself is "controlled" by a sessionScoped Bean. This bean should also handle the long task. Initially the panel shall show a normal text(the loading sign does not have to be updated, a simple gif is enough). After the long task the result should be shown in the panel.

How would you go about the problem or do you think I'm tackling it completely wrong?

Thank you in advance.